# What can be done more with an old ipod touch(First generation)

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

Hi I had an I pod touch (first generation) with version : 1.1.5(4B1) which I bought from EBAy
long time back in 2008

I had installed latest ITunes and browsing if 
I can find any applications that can be run on this 1st gen iPod.
But most of the apps are generally compatible with 3 and greater.

Are there really any  for 1st gen? If no, what else can be done apart from
playing music and videos..

I had seen http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2052 which
says can be updated to iOS3.1. Has anyone done ...any problems faced..

Any other suggestion you have apart from selling it :-)

Comment: ok!!!! Great answers.......but no one has talked about upgrading to 3.1 version..actually buying!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not the best iOS device nowadays but it still makes a nifty remote!
I have an Ipod Touch (2nd gen though) that I use to control my mac-mini media center.
It's very intuitive to manage your playlist (iTunes DJ mode) with the [Remote app](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/).
And I use [Mobile Mouse Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-mouse-pro-remote-trackpad/id289616509?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) to use my Ipod as a mouse. User experience  is not as sweet as Remote but still a great app which eliminates the need for keyboard.

Comment: Great idea!!.....sorry I couldn't up vote since i dont have 15+ votes

Answer (score 2):

I also have a 1st generation iPod Touch.  I have consistently upgradedthe operating system every time an upgrade was available, so I am now running iOS 3.1.

No problems whatsoever, running all sorts of apps, many of which required iOS 3+.

Don't confuse the operating system version with the iPod/iPhone generation (gen 1, 2, 3 or 4).

Comment: Good to hear others using 3.1 in the wild. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can Using your iPod as a storage drive:

[From apple support:](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1478)

> 1. Connect iPod to your computer.
> 2. Open iTunes if it doesn't automatically open.
> 3. Select the iPod icon in the Source pane.
> 4. Click the Summary tab.
> 5. Select "Enable disk use" or "Manually manage music and videos."
>      Either one will allow you to use iPod
>      as a drive. If you select "Manually
>      manage music and videos," iTunes won't
>      automatically update iPod with the
>      iTunes library. If you want iTunes to
>      automatically update your iPod, select
>      "Enable disk use" instead.
> 6. The iPod disk icon appears on the desktop and in Finder windows, and in
>      My Computer/Computer in Windows.
>      Double-click the icon and drag files
>      to or from iPod's window to copy them.
> 7. Make sure to eject iPod before disconnecting it from your computer.
>      Tip: The iPod display will say "Do Not
>      Disconnect" when disk use is enabled
>      (iPod shuffle's status light will
>      continue to blink orange until after
>      it is ejected). These are reminders
>      for you to eject iPod first.

Comment: Cool idea.........I will follow thoroughly!! great...

Comment: I don't think iOS devices allow disk use, I believe that was only for the original iPod line

Comment: This doesn't work with iPhone/iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run apps on that. You've got to upgrade to 3.1.3. I think it costs $10.

Not all apps will run though, but most of them will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could always jailbreak your device you can do loads of cool things like running android or loads of new settings its really good

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please explain in more details how this would work and which steps are needed to do it?