# App compatibility for first gen iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I have recently acquired a first-gen iPod touch updated to iOS 3.3. I'm having trouble installing apps from iTunes as it appears most require iOS 4 and above. So far I have managed to find two games that are still compatible with iOS 3. Not even the Facebook app will install! iTunes says I have the latest iOS available installed.

Is there a way to force install iOS 4? Otherwise, is there a third party repository of older apps I can install from (obviously after jailbreaking)?

Comment: You should look at this post as well, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6569/what-can-be-done-more-with-an-old-ipod-touchfirst-generation?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iOSSearch, a free tool to find apps in the iTunes store which are compatible with iOS 3.1.3](https://sites.google.com/site/iossearch/). This is a non-commercial page I made.

Note: the app store has recently been updated to allow downloads of [last compatible versions](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/09/17/apple-begins-allowing-users-running-legacy-ios-builds-to-download-older-versions-of-apps/) but it appears that this only provides apps which are compatible with iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [whited00r](http://www.whited00r.com/) so you can have an app market with all the iOS 3 compatible apps! It also lets you use multitasking, wallpaper and all the things only newer iPhones/iOS versions have. (http://www.whited00r.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Chris! Thanks for your answer! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to install Whited00r but it keeps failing about half way through. Do I have to jailbreak first? I tried some of the other tools they had to help flash but they didn't work either.